# Understanding element types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have multiple buttons that use a class named submit. I add this reference to jQuery.
When the button is clicked; it should be disabled.

Scripts I could use:

A.`$('.submit').click(function () { this.disabled = true; });`

B.`$('#submit').click(function () { this.prop('disabled'), true); });`

C.`$('#submit').click(function () { $(this).disabled = true; });`

D.`$('.submit').click(function () { $(this).prop("disabled", true); });`

> The correct answer is D.

So, personally, I was pretty sure it was C. (which is wrong) because I saw the `#` before submit. I do this alot with questions like these, where I try to assume I know what the correct selector is. Which I always assume `#` is the correct one.

In hindsight the question states it's a class so I believe that's where the `.` is appropriate.  However, without being told it's a class, I would have just guessed.

Sometimes I see an `id` referenced like so `#imnotaclass` or what have you, which is confusing me.

Can someone better explain jquery selectors to me, when to use `#` , `.`, or  
In jQuery there's documentation on the selectors. Is there not continuity between other languages ie, css, html. I noticed with those 2 I can pass in something and use `#` on all fronts. However it will be an id and yet it still works.

The reason I bring this up is to better understand; on an exam what the correct answer is.

Comment: What is your question? FWIW, D is syntactically  incorrect. A is correct.

Comment: Please show the HTML that goes with this code.

Comment: What about $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); Or $(this).attr("disabled", true);

Comment: # is used as a selector in Jquery that corresponds to an element in a document with an id. Id is unique and can only be used once on one element in a document. You cannot have multiple submit id's. Classes in document are different. you can have multiple same name classes

Comment: "Can someone better explain jquery selectors to me, when to use `#` or `.`" Yeah, it's relational to your HTML/CSS. If you have an element with an `id` of "element", you'd use `$('#element')` or if you have an element with a class of "element", you'd use `$('.element')`. That is how jQuery knows what you want to target. If you want to target multiple elements, most likely you'll use the  `class` of the element. If you want to target a single element, most likely you'll use the `id` of the element.

Comment: I strongly suggest you learn basic HTML and CSS before moving onto JavaScript. Knowledge of those would have answered most of your questions.

Comment: The jQuery selector mirrors CSS selectors (and has a few extensions).  It is apparent you don't know CSS or jQuery very well, not even the basics.  Here's a good start: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 4):

If `"submit"` is a class name, then the correct answer would be A:

```
$('.submit').click(function () { this.disabled = true; });
```

because it is the only answer that selects an element with that class name and properly sets the disabled property inside the event handler.

---

The code inside the event handler is wrong for options B, C and D so there is no way that they could be considered correct.

The question seems to be checking your knowledge of three  things:  1) CSS selector syntax, 2) how to set properties on a DOM element and 3) what is the value of `this` in a jQuery event handler and how you use it.

The two correct ways to set the disabled property inside the event handler are:

```
// use direct DOM property access
this.disabled = true;

// use jQuery's .prop()
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```

---

As for CSS selector syntax basics:

A selector that starts with `#` targets an ID value identified with `id="xxx"` in the HTML or set as a property on the DOM element.

So `"#submit"` references a single element with an id as in

```
<button id="submit">Press Here</button>
```

A selector that starts with `.` targets a class name identified with `class="xxx"` in the HTML or set as a property on the DOM element.

So `".submit"` references one or more objects with a given class name as in

```
<button class="submit">Press Here</button>
```

ID values must be unique in the document (only be used on one single element).  Class names can be used on as many elements as desired.

If you want to see more about the selectors that jQuery uses, you can read [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm).

---

If you were going to use jQuery inside the event handler, it would be this:

```
$('.submit').click(function () { 
    $(this).prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

As shown in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for `.prop()`.

If `"submit"` was an id value, then the correct answer would be:

```
$('#submit').click(function () { 
    $(this).prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

---

Inside your jQuery event handler, the value of `this` will the DOM element that you registered for the event on.  That means if you use something like `this.id`, then you must be referencing DOM properties or calling DOM methods.

If you want to call jQuery methods, then you would use `$(this)` to turn it into a jQuery object so you can then use jQuery methods or properties.

Keep in mind that every jQuery object contains an array of zero or more DOM elements.  You can access the individual DOM elements in the jQuery object via the array syntax as in `$(this)[0]` or via the `.eq()` method as in `$(this).eq(0)` and a jQuery object has a `.length` property which tells you how many DOM elements are in the array as in `$(this).length === 1`.

Comment: It's funny, pointing this out. This is a microsoft exam question, and it goes toward certification. I took this test today and there's many times something like this occurs where it's subjective what the correct answer is. It's infuriating when there's not a perfectly correct answer to choose from.

Comment: @majache - I corrected my answer.  Option A is the only correct answer.  If the question states that "submit" is a class name, then option A is unequivocably the only correct answer.  Option D is not correct because the `.prop()` usage is incorrect.

Comment: @jfriend00 what if it's an input type? microsoft says it D. I can't remember the html  now.

Comment: Then the question is wrong, or you posted it wrong.  D is not correct, ever.  The correct answer is A and it isn't subjective.  B, C, and D are incorrect.  B has a syntax error.  D has two syntax errors. C uses DOM syntax on a jquery object and selects the wrong element.

Comment: @majache - but in D, `$(this)prop.('disabled' = true);` is not correct in any way.  In fact, it's a syntax error.  If using jQuery, then it would be: `$(this).prop("disabled", true);` which is not offered as a choice in any of the answers.

Comment: Wouldn't the syntax today be, $('.submit').on('click',function(event){ $(this).prop('disabled',true); });

Answer (score 1):

This is excerpted from [the documentation](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#selectors). I'm posting this here as supporting information for @jfriend00's answer

Sizzle is the selector engine which jQuery uses.

Note: In supported browsers, jQuery will attempt to use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to resolve CSS selector queries rather than it's internal selector engine if the requested selector does not use jQuery extensions that are not supported by `document.querySelectorAll()`. This is done for performance reasons

> ## Selectors
>
> ### CSS3
>
> Sizzle supports virtually all [CSS 3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), including escaped selectors (`.foo\+bar`), Unicode selectors, and results returned in document order. The only exceptions are those that would require additional DOM event listeners to keep track of the state of elements.
>
> As such, the following pseudo-selectors are *not* supported:
>
> `:hover`
>
> `:active`
>
> `:visited`, `:link`
>
> **Note**: These CSS3 pseudo-selectors were unsupported prior to version 1.9:
>
> `:target`
>
> `:root`
>
> `:nth-last-child`
>
> `:nth-of-type`, `:nth-last-of-type`, `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`, `:only-of-type`
>
> `:lang()`
>
> ### Other selectors and conventions
>
> Changes
>
> Full selector lists in `:not()`; e.g. `:not(a.b)`, `:not(div > p)`, `:not(div, p)`
>
> Nested pseudo-selectors; e.g. `:not(:has(div:first-child))`
>
> Additions
>
> `[NAME!=VALUE]`: Elements whose NAME attribute doesn't match the specified value. Equivalent to `:not([NAME=VALUE])`.
>
> `:contains(TEXT)`: Elements with textContent containing the word 'TEXT'. Case-sensitive.
>
> `:header`: Header elements (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6).
>
> `:parent`: Elements with at least one child node (either text or an element).
>
> `:selected`: (option) elements that are currently selected
>
> Form Selector Additions
>
> **Note**: In this context, `input`, `button`, `select`, and `textarea` are all considered to be input elements.
>
> `:input`: Input elements
>
> `:button`: Input elements that are `button`s or have type "button"
>
> `:checkbox`, `:file`, `:image`, `:password`, `:radio`, `:reset`, `:submit`, `:text`: Input elements with the specified type
>
> Positional Selector Additions
>
> In this context, "positional" refers to an element's placement in the collection after a selection, based on document order. For example, `div:first` would return an array containing the first `div` on the page, while `div:first em` would target the first `div` on the page and select all `em` elements within.
>
> **Note**: Positional indexes begin at zero.
>
> `:first`/`:last`: The first/last matching element
>
> `:even`/`:odd`: Even/odd-numbered elements
>
> `:eq`/`:nth`: The nth element; e.g. `:eq(5)` finds the 6th element
>
> `:lt`/`:gt`: Elements at positions above/below the specified position
>
> https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#selectors

Comment: FYI, in supported browsers, jQuery will attempt to use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to resolve CSS selector queries rather than it's internal selector engine if the requested selector does not use jQuery extensions that are not supported by `document.querySelectorAll()`.  This is done for performance reasons.